# save a cell with different size arrays into excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, cell

`1x3` cell with three arrays of different sizes (`172x2` double, `29x2` double, `165x2` double). How can I save my `1x3` cell into an excel file? Please help

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
C = cell(1,3);
C{1,1} = rand(1,10);
C{1,2} = rand(1,20);
C{1,3} = rand(4,5);
filename = 'myfile.xlsx';
xlswrite(filename,C{1,1},1,'A1:A11');
xlswrite(filename,C{1,2},1,'B1:B21');
xlswrite(filename,C{1,3},1,'C1:G5');
```

[image]